# ¿Cómo conservar datos temporalmente en un array?

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentado almacenar datos de un formulario en un arreglo PHP, le envío los datos por método "POST" pero necesito que almacene más datos o productos con sus respectivas posiciones, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

                $sProducto = $_POST["producto"];
                $sCantidadExistencia = $_POST["cantidad"];
                $sPrecio = $_POST["precioventa"];
                $sCantidadProducto = $_POST["cantidad"];

                $total = $sCantidadProducto * $sPrecio;

                $i = 0;

                for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++)
                {
                    $factura = array($sProducto, $sCantidadExistencia, $sPrecio, $sCantidadProducto, $total);
                }                                                  

                print_r($factura);

                ?>
```

Y el resultado que me da es el siguiente: `Array ( [0] => Pasta INA [1] => 2 [2] => 11.00 [3] => 2 [4] => 22 )`  y si intento guardar otro producto, lo cambia y no guarda otro, ejemplo de nuevo producto ingresado:  `Array ( [0] => Cepillo de Dientes [1] => 2 [2] => 5.00 [3] => 2 [4] => 10 )`

El formulario debe de enviarse varias veces y debe de recordar productos previos, además, el ciclo `for` lo intenté usar para hacer lo que indico, recordar los productos.

Agradecería el apoyo, saludos!

Comment: A ver si entiedo. El formulario solo admite un producto, ¿cierto? Y usted lo que desea es poder enviar varias veces el formulario (¿puede repetirse el producto o siempre va a ser uno diferente?) y que el servidor sea capaz de "recordar" los productos previos? Otra cosa, ¿para qué es el ciclo for?

Comment: Exacto, el formulario debe de enviarse varias veces y si, se puede repetir el producto todas las veces que sean necesarias, y exacto, debe de recordar productos previos, además, el ciclo for lo intenté usar para hacer lo que usted indica, recordar los productos.

Comment: si no cuentas con alguna base de datos para guardar la informacion, puedes usar cookies para mantener los datos, asi obtendrias persistencia y puedes guardar mas datos en la cookie de ser necesario.

Comment: Si tengo base de datos amigo, pero quiero guardarlos o almacenarlos en la base de datos hasta que el usuario le dé a un botón llamado "Finalizar" , ¿como se podría hacer en cookies?

Comment: Utiliza una variable de sesión.

Comment: No sé cómo utilizar la variable de sesión José, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos formas de hacerlo del lado del servidor:

1. Guardando los datos en una tabla.
2. Guardando los datos en la sesión ($_SESSION).

Investigue usted los pros y contras de cada una de ellas. La más simple, no necesariamente la mejor, es la 2.

```
<?php

$sProducto = $_POST["producto"];
$sCantidadExistencia = $_POST["cantidad"];
$sPrecio = $_POST["precioventa"];
$sCantidadProducto = $_POST["cantidad"];

$total = $sCantidadProducto * $sPrecio;

// Este if es probable que no lo necesite, pues en este punto, teniendo 
// a un usuario en el sistema, seguro hay una sesión activa 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// Si ya se envió el formulario al menos una vez, debe existir la factura
// en la sesión, la recuperamos entonces.
if (isset($_SESSION['factura'])) {
    $factura = $_SESSION['factura'];
}

// Adicionar el nuevo producto
$factura[] = array($sProducto, $sCantidadExistencia, $sPrecio, $sCantidadProducto, $total);

// Sobrescribir la factura con la actualizada
// Si es la primera ejecución se crea la variable
$_SESSION['factura'] = $factura;

print_r($factura);
```

Luego en el código de finalizar (que usted mencionó en un comentario) considere "limpiar" la factura almacenada en la sesión, pues si el usuario inicia un nuevo proceso de compra (supongo que de eso se trata) los datos del proceso anterior van a seguir presentes en la nueva factura.

Comment: Funcionó excelente, gracias por tu apoyo, justamente es lo que buscaba, poder almacenarlo y luego hacer un clear para evitar procesos anteriores, gracias eniel, te mereces +1

Comment: @DanielRivas un gusto poderlo ayudar!

Answer (score 2):

Amigo agregando [] al final de tu variable se convierte en un arreglo accesible mediante su indice.

```php
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++){
     $factura[] = array($sProducto, $sCantidadExistencia, 
     $sPrecio,$sCantidadProducto, $total);
     
    }
    //Luego accedes a factura por indice
    print_r($factura[0]) //Posicion 0
    print_r($factura[1]) //Posicion 1
    //Y así con todas la posiciones
?>
```

Comment: Hola Mateo, gracias por tu aporte, lo que necesito es almacenar varios productos dentro de ese array, enviándole datos por el método POST en variables, por lo que necesito es que se vayan almacenando los productos sin que los anteriores se borren, saludos!

Comment: Según lo que te entiendo, la mejor opción seria ir almacenando tus productos en una tabla de la base de datos cada vez que se envía el formulario, luego haces una consulta para acceder a ellos .

Comment: Eso es justo lo que no quiero hacer, hasta que el usuario le dé clic al botón "Terminar Venta"

Comment: Eso requiere usar JavaScript para enviar tu formulario sin recargar la pagina y no perder los datos almacenados en el array.

Answer (score 2):

La forma para poder tener persistencia de la informacion son por medio de cookie, esto lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php

    $factura = [];
    if(isset($_COOKIE['productos'])){ // verifico que cookie exista
        $factura = json_decode($_COOKIE['productos']);
    }
    $sProducto = 1;
    $sCantidadExistencia = 2;
    $sPrecio = 3;
    $sCantidadProducto = 4;
    $factura[] = array($sProducto, $sCantidadExistencia, $sPrecio, $sCantidadProducto);
    setcookie('productos', json_encode($factura), time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Primero verifico si la cookie fue creada, en caso de que exista, obtengo la información y la convierto en array(la cookie solo almacenan String) y se la asigno a la variable que almacenara los siguientes datos

o tambien puedes usar sessiones funcionan igual a las cookies.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $factura = [];
    if(isset($_SESSION['productos'])){ // la cookie existe
        $factura = json_decode($_SESSION['productos']);
    }
    $sProducto = 1;
    $sCantidadExistencia = 2;
    $sPrecio = 3;
    $sCantidadProducto = 4;
    $factura[] = array($sProducto, $sCantidadExistencia, $sPrecio, $sCantidadProducto);
    $_SESSION['productos'] = json_encode($factura);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizar json_encode y json_decode para guardar en $_SESSION?

Comment: Funcionó bien, gracias por tu ayuda tecnobyte, ¿Para que se usa el json_enconde? , saludos.

Comment: utilice el json_encode para convertir en string el arreglo, ya que, tanto la cookie como la session solo permiten string, y el json_decode para convertirlo de nuevo en arreglo.

Comment: A $_SESSION se le puede añadir valores de cualquier tipo, acabo de probar con objetos, cadenas de texto, números, y matrices.  Al menos en PHP 7.3, que es el que estoy utilizando. Creo que este comentario le puede interesar @DanielRivas. Saludos